# jquery toggle function

Tags: javascript

Как провести обратный toggle при клике. Что бы при повторном клике на активный элемент область была скрыта?
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMOEbJ

```
.header__menu-item-entry {display: none;}
```

Comment: можно показывать область только если есть класс active, в таком случае вся скриптовая часть сведется к `toggleClass('active')`

Comment: А как это выглядит на примере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно показывать область только если есть класс `active`, в таком случае вся скриптовая часть сведется к `toggleClass('active')`

Пример:

```js
$(".header__menu-item").on("click", ".header__menu-item-title", function() {
  $(".header__menu-item.active").add($(this).parent()).toggleClass("active");
  return false;
});
```

```css
.header__menu-item-entry {
  display: none;
}
.header__menu-item.active .header__menu-item-entry {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header__menu-item">
  <a href="" class="header__menu-item-title">
    <span>dasds</span><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="header__menu-item-entry">
    <div class="header__menu-item-column"><span>dasdas</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="header__menu-item">
  <a href="" class="header__menu-item-title">
    <span>dasds</span><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="header__menu-item-entry">
    <div class="header__menu-item-column"><span>dasdas</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```